# Sorting pandas df doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I'm currently working on a pandas df imported from pdf. this dataframe only contains 2 columns and approx 15000 rows. I need to sort this df ascending for the frist row and then to substract the lower value of this row to all the other values of the same row. First problem is that I can't manage to sort correctly my dataframe... 
Of course I searched the web and stackoverflow for answers and of course i read the pandas informations about the functions i'm using. Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#import data
dataframe=pd.read_csv('time_and_followers_2.csv', index_col=None)
dataframe.timestamps = dataframe.timestamps.astype(int)

#sort data by first column and get informations needed
sorted_df=dataframe.sort_values(by=['timestamps'])
init_time=sorted_df.at[0,'timestamps']
total_rows = sorted_df.shape[0]

#retrieve initial time to all first column data
sorted_df['timestamps']= sorted_df['timestamps']-init_time
sorted_df.loc[-1] = [init_time,total_rows]  # adding a row
sorted_df.to_csv('time_and_followers_2_sorted.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

and here are the first lines of the csv file:

```
timestamps,followers

1531137667.0,336

1531137650.0,189

1531137638.0,227

1531137617.0,58

1531137616.0,3314
```

any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: How have you arrived at the conclusion that the sort is incorrect? Did you print `df` or `dataframe`?

Comment: Could you please provide a working minimum example?

Comment: You say you want to sort by row descending, and this is exactly what your code did. Did you also want to sort by column? If you want to sort by column, you must specify `axis=1` in your `sort_values` method, as per the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Comment: It is sorted, I'm not sure why you explicitly set `ascending=False` as the flag in `sorted_df=dataframe.sort_values('timestamps', ascending=False)` if you want it to be ascending?

Comment: You have multiple sorting operations, which one do you think isn't working?

Comment: Sorry the code above is a little messy... I'm changing it to make it more readable..

Comment: Please don't post as a comment, you should edit the original question. It will be illegible in a comment.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve my problem! it appeared that  the df was well sorted. The problem was when I tried to acces the first element of my dataset to substract this one to all the others of the same column: as the index was unchanged, i was accessing another element than the minimal one.  a simple `reset_index()` after the sort got me rescued.